# Format text box in SSRS for multiple text

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

i am working in SSRS, I am facing one difficulties since two days. How can i format multiple text in one text-box? i.e Some text i have to show in Bold format and some in normal.
I am getting the Exact output as i have formated in the Textbox when i am running from report builder, But when we have deployed that rdl to the server and looking in the report Viewer, what we are getting is all text in bold format. Its very complex report so dont suggest as to place bold text in separate text box and normal in separate. We cant go with this solution.
Any suggestion will be appreciated? whether we have to put place holder for different-different text's?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are getting the report to look the way you want (some bold some not) in the report builder, but then it all looks bold when you deploy.  How are you accomplishing the dynamic formatting (some bold some not) in the report builder?  If I know how you are doing that, I may be able to figure out why it isn't working when you deploy.

Comment: Yes you are in the right track, Manually i am doing by selecting some of the text as bold which i want and some is in normal.

Comment: Do you have dynamic formatting already? When you say you are doing this manually, does that mean you are exporting the report to Excel and then updating some of the fields to bold in Excel?  If not, then please explain what you mean by "manually".